# CorePlot 0.9: alternatives to isFloatingAxis property

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot

https://github.com/djw/core-plot/tree/9282845bddbb8c40ff314bbfa158beff797c91f7/examples

This states that the isFloatingAxis property has been removed from at least version 0.9.

Does anyone know how to float the x axis without this property?  In other words, if I want the origin of the graph to be (0,6000) lets say, how can I maintain the x axis inside the plot range, while the y axis is NOT set to:

`y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by looking in the CPTTestApp example from the CorePlot_0.9 folder.  I looked in the class files and found this in Controller.m:

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:132];
```

For now, this is holding my x axis in the same spot so I can change the orthogonalCoordinateDecimal to 6000 or whatever without the x axis and labels disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you. It sets the x-axis to range from 0-6000, and makes visible only that part on plot:

```
    axisSet.xAxis.visibleRange =[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(6000)];
    axisSet.xAxis.gridLinesRange = axisSet.xAxis.visibleRange;
```